# Question regarding error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, function, package

I have created this function to automate multinomial regression:

```
multinom<-function(form,ref,db){
  library(VGAM)
  mod<-vglm(formula(form),multinomial(refLevel = ref),data = db)
  t1<-exp(cbind(OR = coef(mod), confint(mod)))
  p_val<-coef(summary(mod))[,4]
  x<-data.frame(cbind(t1,p_val))
  x$prob<-x[,1]/(1+x[,1])
  colnames(x)<-c("OR","CI_min","CI_max","P_val","Probablity")
  return(x)
}
```

When this function is used in a script, it works just fine. I have also added this function to a package I am writing:

```
##############################
#' Statistical analysis: Multinomial Regression
#'
#'The purpose of this function is to calculate the Odds Ratio for a statistical analysis that involves a categorical dependent variable, with more than two unordered levels or classes, and different independent variables of any kind.
#'The Odds Ratio is obtained using a multinominal logit regression. This is an extension of the binomial logistic regression to allow for a categorical dependent variable with more than two unordered categories.
#'In multinomial regression we need to define a reference variable category. The model will determine several binomial distribution parameters with respect to the reference category.
#' @param form model formula. For example: `dep_var~conf_var1+conf_var2+conf_var3`.
#' @param ref reference category from the dependent variable. If its a character variable the reference level must be included in `""`.
#' @param df D.B_Final database obtained from the data incorporation step.
#' @return A table with the Odds ratio, its 95% CI and the associated p-value.
#' @export
#' @examples
#' # Basic Usage of Multinomial Regression.
#' multinom(cov_2~cov_3+var_con,"A",D.B_Final)
#'
multinom<-function(form,ref,db){
  library(VGAM)
  mod<-vglm(formula(form),multinomial(refLevel = ref),data = db)
  t1<-exp(cbind(OR = coef(mod), confint(mod)))
  p_val<-coef(summary(mod))[,4]
  x<-data.frame(cbind(t1,p_val))
  x$prob<-x[,1]/(1+x[,1])
  colnames(x)<-c("OR","CI_min","CI_max","P_val","Probablity")
  return(x)
}
```

When this function is used inside the corresponding package, specifically as `zoombedo::multinorm`, I encounter the error message: `Error in object$coefficients: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.`

Can anyone help me to understand what is going on here?

Comment: don't load a library inside a function. Define depedecies for your package instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a perfect solution but I think I can explain the problem.  The error is almost certainly coming from your `coef(summary(mod))[,4]`. This *should* be calling the `coef()` method for an object of class `summary.vglm`:

```r
selectMethod("coef", "summary.vglm")
Method Definition:

function (object, ...) 
object@coef3
<bytecode: 0x5617c6d9d8e8>
<environment: namespace:VGAM>
```

This is apparently not found in the package context. Instead, what you get is `stats:::coef.default()`:

```r
function (object, complete = TRUE, ...) 
{
    cf <- object$coefficients
    if (complete) 
        cf
    else cf[!is.na(cf)]
}
```

Since the object doesn't have an `$coefficient` element, you get the error.

The hacky way to solve this would be to access the `@coef3` slot directly.

Using `importMethodsFrom("VGAM", "summary")` in your `NAMESPACE` file(or `@importMethodsFrom` if you're using roxygen) and maybe `importClassesFrom("VGAM", "summary.vglm")` *might* solve the problem (see the [R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Namespaces-with-S4-classes-and-methods) document), but I haven't tested.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I finally changed the function so now is like this:
```multinom<-function(form,ref,db){
  mod<-VGAM::vglm(formula(form),VGAM::multinomial(refLevel = ref),data = db)
  t1<-exp(cbind(OR = coef(mod), confint(mod)))
  p_val<-dt(VGAM::summary(mod)@coef3[,3],1)``` However now I have create another issue. when trying to roxygenise() I get the following error: No methods found in package ‘VGAM’ for request: ‘vglm’ when loading ‘zoombedo’

Comment: see corrected `importFrom` syntax (the first argument is the package name, which should be "VGAM", not "vglm"